# Creating a consortium blockchain network using ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I want to create a consortium blockchain on the local environment using truffle and ganache or any other tools. 
**The problem is** I am new to blockchain though I have created a public DApp by watching some tutorials I don't know how to start working any consortium app.
All I could found on some blogs are functional terms and how consortium works, not the implementation. I know the concepts of consortium members and validators. These are a few questions I am struggling to answer:

1. How to add nodes in the consortium?
2. Do I have to write the logic for validating a node in smart contracts?
3. Where can I find more resources to implement this blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum is a public blockchain. If you need to use it for a permissioned consortium blockchain, you have to do some modifications which require a lot of Ethereum programming experience and take nontrivial work.

[Quorum](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum) is an Ethereum-based distributed ledger protocol with transaction/contract privacy and new consensus mechanisms, of which I think you can take advantage for your goal.